# "is usually not" vs "is not usually"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

> Politics is usually not a safe topic for conversation.
>
> Politics is not usually a safe topic for conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, they both are. [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20usually%20not%2Cis%20not%20usually&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20usually%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20usually%3B%2Cc0) shows that both are in common use, with a slight preference to 'is usually not' (note that the usage has switched in the last 50 years). Maybe there's a difference in emphasis — to me, 'is usually *not*' and 'is not *usually*'.